# Redundant shooting code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Summary:** I am wondering if my code is needlessly redundant. I noticed, when looking over my code that I had a unnecessary variable and if statement. Both Fire() methods achieve the desired result without error (from what I have seen). To me the Redundant Fire Method reads allot nicer and is my preferable method but I'm just wondering if the Alternate Fire Method is still worth the trade off in readability due to efficiency. I am also wondering if there may be any underlying bugs that may occur in either of my methods that I am unaware of.

**EDIT:**
Unity version 4.6.3

**Fire Method Result:** when the space key is pressed - spawns a laser that fires upwards towards the enemy at the preset speed and is delayed by the reload time.

**Desired result:** when the space key is pressed - spawn a laser and have it fire in an upwards direction towards the enemies at the preset speed and than have a delay equal to the preset reload time.

**Variables:**

```
public float reloadTime = 0.2f;
public GameObject playerProjectilePrefab;
public float playerProjectileSpeed = 10f;

private bool canShoot = true;
private float reloadCountDown;
```

**Redundant Fire Method:**

```
void Fire (){
    Vector3 startPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0 ,(renderer.bounds.size.y * 0.5f), 0);

    if (canShoot && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        canShoot = false;
        GameObject playerProjectile = Instantiate(playerProjectilePrefab, startPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        playerProjectile.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, playerProjectileSpeed, 0);
        reloadCountDown = reloadTime;
    } else if (!canShoot){
        reloadCountDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (reloadCountDown <= 0f){
        canShoot = true;
    }
}
```

**Alternate Fire Method:**

```
void Fire (){
    Vector3 startPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0 ,(renderer.bounds.size.y * 0.5f), 0);

    if (reloadCountDown <= 0f && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        GameObject playerProjectile = Instantiate(playerProjectilePrefab, startPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        playerProjectile.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, playerProjectileSpeed, 0);
        reloadCountDown = reloadTime;
    } else if (reloadCountDown > 0f){
        reloadCountDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The scope of this question seems better suited for the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @MrD Alright, thanks I will re-post it there when I am allowed to ask another question (40 minutes).

Comment: What Unity version are you using and please put **Edit** in your question and describe what happens in the Fire function. That will help determine if it needs more imporvement

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for the advice and edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you the code in the function do,the first code is a little bit redundant but the second fixed it.

Since you mentioned efficiency, you can still optimize the second code.

Your next problem is on this line of code:

```
GameObject playerProjectile = Instantiate(playerProjectilePrefab, startPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Doing that, you are allocating memory each time you shoot. If you are going to instantiate Object more than **once**, then **Object Pooling** should be implemented. All it does it to re-use the already Instantiated GameObject.

It is very likely you have `Destroy(gameObject)` in your code which is also costly. If you don't, well that is worse because you are creating new Objects without destroying the old ones. Once Object Pooling is implemented, you won't need to use `Instantiate` and `Destroy` again. You just use your Pooling script to return available GameObject to use.

[Here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling?playlist=17117) you can learn about implementing your own Object pooling in Unity.

**Other Notes**:

When you upgrade to Unity 5,

`playerProjectile.rigidbody2D.velocity` becomes `playerProjectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity`.

`renderer.bounds.size.y` becomes `gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y`

Since `renderer.bounds` is the-same as `gameObject.renderer.bounds` and you want efficient code, you should cache the `renderer` in the `Start()` function.

```
Renderer cachedRender = null;
void Start()
{
    cachedRender = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
}
```

Then in your `Fire()` function, you can use it like:

```
cachedRender.bounds.size.y * 0.5f
```